# Как нормально пользоваться гибридной графикой на убунту?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, графика, nvidia, видеокарта

Я решил переходить на линукс, поэтому начал рассматривать разные варианты. Сначала думал manjaro, но мой друг посоветовал Pop!_OS, я подумал, почему бы и нет, ведь у него тем более была загрузочная флешка с Pop!_OS. Я его поставил второй ОС с виндой. У меня гибридная графика(NVIDIA + Intel), и когда я решил поиграть в CS:GO(на Windows 10 было 40-70 фпс), то только в лобби было 8 фпс, а на карту вообще не заходило. Я подумал, что надо установить драйвера, сначала пробовал проприетаные NVIDIA, но у меня перестал работать линукс. Тогда я переустановил его и попробовал установить bumblebee - безрезультатно, снова перестал работать линукс. Теперь я установил специальную версию Pop!_OS для NVIDIA(как говорилось с проприетарными драйверами), но фпс тот же, а когда я вписываю команду `lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA`, то выдаёт:    `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:0f31] (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`, что, как я понял, значит, что NVIDIA не работает. Можете помочь сделать так, чтобы гибридная графика работала нормально?

Вот фото про систему, которое я сделал с винды
[image: фото про систему, которое я сделал с винды]

Comment: Если поставили bumblebee, то игру стоит запускать через него. Обычно для этого достаточно добавить в начало команды primusrun или optirun.

Comment: "а вна карту" - это просто опечатка или сознательно?

Comment: "вна" — это опечатка, должно быть "на карту" (типа мираж, даст и тд)

Comment: Ладно, я попробую скачать бамблби, и посмотреть, что там с ним.

Comment: Наконец добрался до этого, всё из-за школы. Я вродее установил бамблби, но оптиран не работает(`[ERROR]Could not connect to /var/run/bumblebee.socket! Error: Connection refused
[ 1297.472318] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?`). Ещё при установке я заметил следующие строки: No `Nvidia card found. If you really have an Optimus system,
try selecting the Optimus setup in BIOS and run:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure bumblebee`
Что дальше?

Comment: а может все таки напишите полный вывод lspci и крайне желательно модель ноута/неттопа. Может там какой то хитрый видоеконтроллер?

Comment: Модель ноута: Lenovo 80G0. Вродее полный вывод и есть `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:0f31] (rev 0e) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`, но точно смогу сказать чуть позднее.

Comment: В самом вопросе добавил фото, сделаное с винды, где я постарался запечатлить все данные о компе

Comment: что то я не могу тут найти nvidia карту. И [сторонние ресурсы](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=4923afadbb) это подтверждают. Поэтому, установка nvidia драйверов ничего не сделает. В интернетах люди жалуются, что видео подвисает на этом ноуте, не только в играх, а и в браузере. я даже пока не знаю, как можно с этим помочь

Comment: Ну ладно, возможно, скоро смогу получить новый ноутбук, то там будут дела по-лучше